# What's the point of using Tasks if I have to create my own STA Threads to run them in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, taskscheduler

I've done a lot of reading and watching Microsoft's videos on why I should use Tasks and not threads and it makes sense (I think). But this blog from Microsoft on [Parallel Programming with .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/07/parallelextensionsextras-tour-5-stataskscheduler/) has me confused.

My understanding is by using Tasks I can take better advantage of multiple cores and have these tasks run in parallel. The problem is I'm making calls to native code that instantiates some COM objects so my Tasks have to run on STA threads.

In this article the author says to get a Task to run on an STA thread you have to create the task from an STA thread. He creates ONE STA thread and creates 10 tasks from it, then comments that all the tasks will run sequentially due to creating the tasks from one thread.

Wait... why? If I have to create my own threads to get my Tasks to run in parallel, doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose? And why don't they run in parallel?

What am I missing?

Comment: is he talking about single core in this case? Then it would make sense that all threads run sequentially. Actually he is. Look at number of threads: var sta = new StaTaskScheduler(numberOfThreads:1);

Comment: Yes and no.  Using tasks is usually a much cleaner abstraction, and C# has some additional capabilities when using them.  You're not actually guaranteed that they run in parallel, though - they're put in a queue, and they wait to be picked up by an existing thread (more or less).  Although you're not really guaranteed that native threads run in parallel either, since you depend on the OS for scheduling and context switching.  I'd imagine someone's already written a native task scheduler, though, so you might be able to use an existing library.

Comment: As author says: "In general, it’s desirable to avoid STA objects".

Comment: One argument for using Tasks instead of Threads is to eliminate the context switching. I'm running in a VM with 2 CPUs and the tasks are running sequentially. Unless I use that code in that article and then they run sequentially on the multiple threads that get created. So where's the performance gain? I'm not getting it.

Comment: @YuriS... of course... but also read that it's necessary for COM objects. So I don't have a choice.

Comment: I assume you tried to change number of threads in StaTaskScheduler constructor. What do you get then?

Comment: @YuriS, That class creates thread to create tasks. When the value is one, than ALL tasks run sequentually. If the value is two than two threads are created to pull tasks out of a container and execute them sequentially on two different threads. So if they don't run in parallel and I still have to create threads to manage my tasks, what's the point? Seems like just another layer to go through when the threads can just execute the tasks directly.

Answer (score 3):

> If I have to create my own threads to get my Tasks to run in parallel, doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose? And why don't they run in parallel?

Well the problem specific to your case is that you are interacting with a *Single Threaded Apartment* (STA) COM object.  STA means it is not thread safe.

Most if not all UI COM objects (e.g. anything in Microsoft Office Ole Automation) are not thread safe either by design or for historical reasons and must be invoked from the thread that created them.  All such method calls are sent via the Windows Message Pump hence why they are serialised.

It is no different if you attempted to update your own UI from a worker thread - you can't.

> What's the point of using Tasks if I have to create my own STA Threads to run them in parallel?

1. Well according to that article you are ultimately creating your own task scheduler not just *"create my own ... threads"*.  Custom task schedulers are not a bad thing and TPL allows for this by design
2. You'll never be able to call STA COM objects in parallel if they all belong to the same process

### Conclusion

It seems you are perhaps blaming TPL for this COM STA problem which is slightly unfair.  STA thread problems persist whether you avoid TPL entirely and use your own threads; if you attempt to call STA COM objects from say c++; or when using DCOM via networked computers on a LAN.

Comment: In the article there is no COM being used in the first example use, but the Tasks are running on one thread. Are you trying to suggest that just by making them an MTA thread they will run in parallel? And if not, would you agree there is no performance gain to using Tasks in this example? In fact, it's just additional overhead.

Comment: @tdemay Well no, the _entire_ article is about COM.  Why?  Because he is talking about STA which is purely a COM concept.  No, if you make a MTA thread that in turn attempts to call a COM object it will either not respond or your thread will crash with _[attempt to call object from a thread not belonging to the created thread]_

Comment: @tdemay _"...would you agree there is no performance gain to using Tasks..."_ - there is no performance gain in attempting to use distributed computing either, like say DCOM to call the exact same object. Here, DCOM can be thought of as an analagy to threads.  Ultimately however all calls are serialised in the target process.  Like attempting to update a GUI control, ultimately only one thing can be updated at a time.  STA COM is no different.  Attempting any trickery won't make it go any faster

Comment: You aren't answering the question I am trying to ask. Forget about COM for a minute. Are you saying that tasks run sequentially from an STA thread and they run parallel from an MTA thread? If that is what you are saying than I don't understand the point of the article. Why bother using tasks at all In STA threads?  If that isn't what you are saying then I don't understand how tasks can be used in place of threads  for parallel computing.

Comment: @tdemay To put it simply, **yes, to use `Task` with STA COM is a complete waste of time**.  I believe that using `Task` where only one task at a time can be allowed to run is just silly irrespective of whether it is COM or not. I believe that article you linked to is probably better served as how one can make their own task scheduler, but to do so that only one task can run at a time (as in COM STA) is just ridiculous.  If you ask me it is an example of MS right hand not knowing what the left hand is doing or is an excercise at extreme cleverness that serves no point.

Comment: @tdemay If your code must call something one thread at a time whether it is COM or not, don't bother with `Task`. Hope that helps

Comment: And yes, MTA means there is no serialisation of COM calls, so they run in parallel.  This is only useful for COM objects marked MTA. The same MTA COM object can be called concurrently by multiple threads or in your case `Task`s